# Является ли мой способ позиционирования элементов правильным?

Tags: html, css

Выровнял блок с помощью wrapper'a, его я растянул на 100vh. Потом использовал Flex для позиционирования блока по центру. Является ли этот способ правильным? И каким еще образом можно выставлять высоту блоков на весь экран? Как сделать этот блок адаптивным?

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #2A303A;
}

.wrapper{
        display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{
    width: 916px;
    height: 305px;
    background-color: #323A46;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, является. Можно ещё фиксировано указывать высоту блока в `px` `em`... в зависимости от задачи. Очень редко в таком возникает необходимость, для адаптивных случаев обычно указывают значение `min-height` этого достаточно